# Why am I getting slapped around by giant fish?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

I'm playing Recettear, and in the "Jade Way" dungeon, I appear to randomly be assaulted by screen-wide, giant fish.

They're not particularly hard to dodge (once you stop being *surprised* by them) and don't deal much damage, but I'd like to know what's causing it in the first place. Is it a special attack of one of the enemies?

Comment: And now for something completely different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a special attack done by any of the enemies. It's one of the random trap-type occurrences that can happen in a square, like the rocks falling. There's really no way to predict it happening at all. You just have to dodge carefully.

Comment: The real question is: Why on earth is the trap loaded with *fish*?

Comment: @Canageek Because Japan 